# Здравствуйте, как правильно записать числитель ?(без pow) (это Ci) prod=(3*i*i * ln(i+1)-так же вроде нельзя

Tags: c, математика, ряды

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Здравствуйте, как правильно записать числитель ?(без pow) (это Ci)
prod=(3*i*i * ln(i+1)-так же вроде нельзя

Comment: Его **не надо** записывать явно.

Comment: "так же вроде нельзя" - кто Вам запретит?

Comment: Это лабораторна робота и одно из условий-это написать код не используя pow

Comment: Напишите свой pow, в этом вроде и есть суть таких лабораторных

Comment: Как вариант еще заменить 3^i на примерно такое (предполагая что вы считаете сумму в цикле): перед циклом `int multiplier = 1;` в начале цикла `multiplier *= 3;` а числитель будет `multiplier * ln (i+1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите написать свой `pow` или это требуется в условиях лабораторной работы, то вот простой вариант, который покрывает отрицательные и нулевую степень.

```
#include <math.h>

double Power(double ValueToPow, int DegreeOfValue) 
{
    double Result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < abs(DegreeOfValue); i++)
    {
        Result *= ValueToPow;
    }
    return DegreeOfValue >= 0 ? Result : 1.0 / Result;
}
```

А касательно `ln`, для этого Вы можете использовать `log`, в Си это и есть натуральный логарифм.

Answer (score 2):

Рассмотрите отношение двух соседних членов ряда, и вы увидите, что эта сумма считается, что называется, в одну строку...

```
double series(unsigned int n)
{
    double sum = 0, term = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) sum += log(i+1)*(term *= 3.0/(2*i+1));
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Это и есть весь код?

Comment: Поиска суммы? да.

Comment: При его компиляции выдаёт ошибки: 1)undefined referenced to 'Winmain@16'    2) ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Блин, ну компилируйте консольное приложение, зачем вы установили оконное? Если вы купили машину, и вогнались в столб по неумению водить - вы претензии продавцу выкатываете? я вам дал нормально ездящую машину, а уж выполнять ПДД - знаете, это уже за вами.

Comment: Здесь спасибо - слева :) - птичка, означающая, что ответ принят...